# Visual Studio Class Navigator

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In C#, Is there a Navigator to look through the hierarchy of a class?

- I know there is a drop down menu at the top of an open CS file,
- and I know there is a Class View window, this is pretty close.. But this does not cooperate with the file you open. You have to sort through it manually as if it were a file explorer itself.

But this isn't very useful compared to the likes of Netbeans own Navigator they have. The file you open has a list of all the properties and methods for the classes within the file, it's so convenient.

I know there must be something better for this masterpiece Visual Studio, am I wrong?

Comment: Using one source file for one class is a very common way to organize code.  Makes this problem disappear.  Were you a C++ programmer in a previous life?

Comment: One file for all my classes seems a little crazy. I am used to PHP, Im known as as a Script Kiddie gone professional LOL